# Facebook style message bubble using span

Tags: html, css

I'm using an `<ul>` with `<li>` to show a string of messages like on facebook. I'm using span because i only want the length of the message to have the background color and border. Ive tried to make a div inside the li  with an width at auto and using `<p>` tags to achieve this but only span is doing it so far. However with the span when the line breaks it looks like this:

[image: weird breakage of the span background]

[image]
**HTML**

```
<ul>    
    <li class = "msg_list" data-soyid = "{{$message->user_id}}">
        <div style = "width: auto" class = "fl_bx">
           <section>
                <span>
                        {{$message->body}}
                </span>
            </section>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.msg_list{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.msg_list span{
    padding: 3px;
    background: beige;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.user_chat{
    text-align: right;
}
.response_chat{
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle and/or a screenshot of what functionality you're trying to replicate? The Facebook chat bubbles look different between mobile phones, desktop, and what mobile OS you're using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a span is not a block element you should add this CSS rule to your span: `display:inline-block;`

Try it here:

```css
.msg_list{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.msg_list .msg{
    padding: 3px;
    background: beige;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    
}


.user_chat{
    text-align: right;
}
.response_chat{
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>    
<li class = "msg_list" data-soyid = "{{$message->user_id}}">
        <div style = "width: auto" class = "fl_bx">
           <section>
                <span class="msg">
                        very looooooooooooooooooooooooooong line.
                </span>
            </section>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can easily change container width and play with it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z8sL5ht4/1/)

Comment: Ah yes. Learning new things everyday. Thanks Chris